# stacked bar using data from YouTube

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I am fetching data from `YouTube` **API** to plot `VideoCategories` and the `country` in a stacked plot **Bar** `chart`:

I`m Trying:

```
country_category4 = df_AnzahlTag[['channelCountry', 'videoCategoryName']]
test5 = country_category4.set_index('channelCountry')['videoCategoryName'].value_counts()
test5.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @rpanai what additional inforamtion is needed? Im releatively fresh to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Just use `unstack()`:

```py
df.groupby('channelCountry')['videoCategoryName'].value_counts().unstack().plot(kind="bar", stacked="True")
```

plot:
[image]

by category

```py
df.groupby('videoCategoryName')['channelCountry'].value_counts().unstack().plot(kind="bar", stacked="True")
```

[image]

Maybe not that meaningful as I hoped, but at least if shown by language is clearly shows the dominance of the english language when it comes to *Music*

```py
df.groupby('videoCategoryName')['videoTitleLanguage'].value_counts().unstack().plot(kind="bar", stacked="True")
```

[image]

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67111912/revisions) to the question [stacked bar using data from YouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111912/stacked-bar-using-data-from-youtube) by the OP [SemperVirens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15565684/sempervirens) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>